# Get boolean from aspx page using ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I want to open a new window based on whether the current user is an admin or a user. Upon the user pressing the F1 key, I want the system to check the current asp.net user role.

I have never done this sort of thing before, and this is all I could come up with. I'm having trouble getting the boolean value returned to the ajax call.

AJAX call:

```
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 112) {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/check/role.aspx",
                data: {},
                dataType: "json",
                success: function () {
                    if (role == true) {
                        window.open(url, "popupWindow", "width=600,height=600,scrollbars=yes");
                    }
                }
            });
        };
    });
```

ASPX page:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" %>

<script runat="server">

Sub Page_Load(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim CurrentUser As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser()

    If (Roles.IsUserInRole(CurrentUser.UserName, "Admin")) Then

        role = true
        'return true that user is an admin and can open popup

    End If

End Sub

</script>
```

Comment: Are you **sure** you need AJAX to accomplish this? Seems like overkill. Just write the variable into the script by using some `<%` inline tags.

Comment: Can those inline tags be used in an html page?

Comment: You specifically said that this is an ASPX page. Those tags are available on ASPX page. They'll be processed on the server side and the results will be included on the resulting HTML sent to the client. See [Embedded Code](http://weblogs.asp.net/ahmedmoosa/archive/2010/10/06/embedded-code-and-inline-server-tags.aspx) blog.

Answer (score 0):

Your success function does not contain the response, hence you cannot access the value in the response you are looking for.

At the very least you should capture the response:

```
    success: function (data) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's do it without AJAX...

```
var isAdmin= <%= GetIsAdmin() %>;
$(document).keyup(function (e)
{
    if (e.which == 112)
    {
        if(isAdmin)
        {
            window.open(url, "popupWindow", "width=600,height=600,scrollbars=yes");
        }
    }
});
```

On server side,

```
Public Function GetIsAdmin() As String
    Dim CurrentUser As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser()
    If (Roles.IsUserInRole(CurrentUser.UserName, "Admin")) Then
        return True;
    End If
End Sub
```

You just use an inline function to get the value when the page loads. No need to make an asynchronous call. That'd only be necessary if the admin status changes between the time the page loads and the time you hit the F1 key. But even then, a simple refresh of the page would update the variable so AJAX is really overkill.

Comment: @Jrags87 see my comment on your question. Please try it out and let us know if this doesn't work.